# DataSet TableAdapter Fill Method

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dataset

I have a DataSet with two TableAdapters (1 to many relationship) that was created using visual studio 2010's Configuration Wizard.

I make a call to an external source and populate a Dictionary with the results. These results should be all of the entries in the database. To synchronize the DB I don't want to just clear all of the tables and then repopulate them like dropping the tables and creating them with new data in sql.

Is there a clean way possibly using the TableAdapter.Fill() method or do I have to loop through the two tables row by row and decide if it stay or gets deleted and then add the new entries? What is the best approach to make the data that is in the dictionary be the only data in my two tables with the DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

First Question: if it's the same DB why do you have 2 tables with the same information?

To the question at hand: that largley depend on the sizes. If the tables are not big then use a transaction, clear the table (DELETE * FROM TABLE or whatever) and write your data in there again.
If the tables are big on the other hand the question is: can you load all this into your dictionary?

Of course you have to ask yourself what happens to inconsistent data (another user/app changed the data while you had it in your dictionary).

If this takes to long you could remember what you did to the data - that means: flag the changed data and remember the deleted keys and new inserted rows and make your updates based on that.

Both can be achieved by remembering the Filled DataTable and use this as backing field or by implementing your own mechanisms.

In any way I would recommend think on the problem: do you really need the dictionary? Why not make queries against the database to get the data? Or only cache a part of the data for quick access?

PS: the update method on you DataAdapter will do all the work (changing the changed, removing the deleted and inserting the new datarows but it will update the DataTable/Set so this will only work once)

Comment: I only have access to the db that I am modifying. The other db is coming somewhere in active directory and I only have access through System.DirectoryServices api so I am storing the results in hash data structure. Is there a way to use sql directly like that if I only have access to the DataSet?

Comment: can you write to the AD-database? If so why use your onw database at all (performance?) Maybe you can find a way to cooperate with the AD's database-expert?

Comment: I can only read from AD. I am required to use my own DB by my boss mainly because of performance. It is a small subset of the data that is stored in AD but I wouldn't want to write to it because AD is like the master database and I'm mimicking a small subset of it.

Comment: well than you cannot keep the data sync - just copy the data once and use only your own DB - take the Linq2Sql or DataSet approach thats the easiest one...

Comment: It is only going to be synced a few times a day with a DataSet. I was looking for more info on how the fill method works or the best approach to replace all the data in a table.

Comment: I was trying to prevent looping through the data multiple times by changing the dictionary to a DataTable and then calling the update method but that provides duplicates (not to DB since there is an id PK)

Comment: I was trying to prevent looping through the data multiple times by changing the dictionary to a DataTable and then calling the update method but that provides duplicates (not to DB since there is an id PK) so I tried merge with the same results. this.groupsTableAdapter.Update(newGroupsTable); Is there a way to accomplish this or do I have to go back to my manual method?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it is quicker to repopulate the entire table than to itterate through and decide what record go / stay. Could you not do the process of deciding if a records is deleteed via an sql statement ? (Delete from table where active = false) if you want them to stay in the database but not in the dataset (select * from table where active = true)

You could have a date field and select all records that have been added since the date you late 'pooled' the database (select * from table where active = true and date-added > #12:30#)

Comment: I was thinking it might be easier to just create a new table with the DataTable and DataRow classes and then pass that into the Fill method?  I have been trying to think of a sql statement that would do this for me but it is going to be more complicated than looking at an active column. I have a table of groups and then a table of members with a fk to the group that they belong to.

Comment: @Ben SQL is a powerfull data manipulation language, you can create temp tables from selected fields with ease, even append other tables to one another ... maybe you need to take a step back and look at the bigger picture ?

Comment: Wish I could ... boss and other team members are requiring me to do it this way.